# NSNotification never being sent

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm trying to use the NSNotificationCenter with Swift and I'm running into a problem. I'm trying the following:

```
class MyClass {

    init() {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "stopTimer", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: [])
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        println("Entered background!")
    }
}
```

When hitting the home button, the observer is never calling the selector, therefore my message is never being printed out.

Notice that I send an empty object at the end, the method signature for `addObserver` is expecting an implicitly unwrapped object and setting it to `nil` results in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when the app enters background.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that this code is being executed from a framework included in my project.

Executing the code gives me a bad access abort signal.

[image]

Comment: I have replaced [] with nil and it worked for me

Comment: You're not "sending an empty object at the end". `[]` is an array - isn't it?

Comment: Yes, empty array, which is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out. 2 problems:

- There was no strong reference to the instance of my class in my app
- My class wasn't extending `NSObject`

Now, I can set `object: nil` and everything works fine.

Thanks for all your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to pass nil for an optional argument. Can you elaborate more on what happens if you do? This is working for me:

```
func init() {
    super.init()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "stopTimer", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil) 
}

func stopTimer() {
    println("Entered background!")
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: I'm not using a superclass, no need for `super.init()`.

Comment: Oops, yeah I used a super class when I was testing it out. Still should work with the "nil" parameter. If you send an empty array ("[]") then you would get a crash because the stopTimer function cannot take a parameter.

Comment: Are you sure the class instance hasn't been released by the time you go to background? It sounds like the call to stopTimer is trying to access a bad address, such as an object instance that's already been garbage collected. I added the code for deinit that would prevent this from happening.

Comment: Yep, the instance was getting released. Another issue was that because it wasn't extending `NSObject` (or any other class that would inherit `NSObject`), I was missing the `methodSignatureForSelector:` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try implementing `applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication)` instead?

To further troubleshoot, you may also want to add a log statement to your app delegate's `deinit` to see if the delegate gets deallocated after entering the background.